# Ruby -- use a string as a variable name to define a new variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, metaprogramming

I have an array of strings:

```
names = ['log_index', 'new_index']
```

What I want to do is to create variables from the names:

```
names.each { |name| name = [] } # obviously it does not do what I want
```

Those variables are not declared before anywhere in the code.

How could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by string in a variable name?

Comment: Where does the `index` array come from? Why don't you just assign the variables manually via `log_index = []` and `new_index = []`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to define **new local variables** dynamically in Ruby.

It was possible in Ruby 1.8 though with `eval 'x = 2'`.

You can change an existing variable with `eval` or `binding.local_variable_set`.

I would consider using `hash` to store values.

Comment: I agree with the `hash` mentality in this case even something as simple as `index.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) {|i,obj| obj[i]}`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically define local variables in ruby, but you can dynamically define instance variables:

```
names = ['log_index', 'new_index']
names.each { |name| instance_variable_set("@#{name}", []) }
```

This gives you:

```
@log_index
 => [] 
@new_index
 => []
```

You can also dynamically access instance variable with `instance_variable_get`:

```
names = ['log_index', 'new_index']
names.each { |name| puts instance_variable_get("@#{name}").inspect }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack:

```
names.each { |name| eval "def #{name}; []; end"  }
```

Comment: In this case `define_method` seems more appropriate than `eval`. That being said it will always return an empty Array which does not seem very useful since I assume the intent is to store information in it.